# QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'null' near line 1

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have some troubles in running a query with Hibernate. Given the following entity...

```
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "configuration")
@IdClass(ConfigurationPk.class)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Configuration implements Persistable<UUID> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Setter
    private UUID id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    @Setter
    private int version;

    @Column(name = "close_date")
    @Setter
    private LocalDateTime closeDate;

    @Column(name = "definition")
    @Lob
    @Setter
    private String definition;

    public boolean isNew() {
        return closeDate == null;
    }
}
```

... and the following composite primary key:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class ConfigurationPk implements Serializable {

    private UUID id;
    private int version;
}
```

I tried to associate a custom query with the `findAll` method:

```
@Repository
public interface ConfigurationRepository extends JpaRepository<Confguration, UUID> {
    ...

    @Query(value = "SELECT c FROM Configuratin c"
      + " WHERE c.closeDate IS NULL"
      + " AND (c.id, c.version) IN (SELECT c.id, MAX(c.version) AS version"
      + " FROM Configuration c GROUP BY c.id ORDER BY c.id)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Configuration> findAll();
}
```

The query above looks fine to me... but if we look the the error message, it seems the final closing parenthesis is missing:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found 'null' near line 1, column 281 [select count(q) FROM com.avaloq.awp.profiling.persistence.model.questionnaire.QuestionnairePo q WHERE q.closeDate IS NULL AND (q.id, q.version) IN (SELECT q.id, MAX(q.version) AS version FROM com.avaloq.awp.profiling.persistence.model.questionnaire.QuestionnairePo q GROUP BY q.id]
```

Am I missing something? Thank u very much.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?  [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/) not all DBMS support the `(a,b) in (select x,y...)` syntax

Comment: I'm using hsqldb to run my integration test...